# ExtJS 4, resetting checkboxgroup

Tags: extjs, checkbox, extjs4

Could you help me please to reset (uncheck) all checkboxes in checkboxgroup. I'd like to know if there's a one command to do it, not using a loop.

e.g. `Ext.getCmp('faqsModelsCheckboxGroup').reset()` - doesn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've found solution:

`Ext.getCmp('faqsModelsCheckboxGroup').setValue(false)`
[image]

Comment: I need to wait 23 hours to do it - stackoverfl rules